# Criação de botão dinâmico

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá.
Estou me batendo para criar um botão para cada resultado que o `$.each` gera.

```
 $.each (data, function(index, orc){
           $html += '<div>';
           $html += '<button type="button" class="list-group-item" id="btn_orc'+orc.numero+'">Número: ' +orc.numero+'</br>Data: '+orc.data+'</br>Validade: '+orc.validade+'</br>Total: R$'+orc.total+'</br>'+'</button>';
           $html += '</div>';
    });
    $('#lista').html($html);
   // aqui não sei como implementar
   $('#btn_orc').on('click', function(){
        window.alert("clicou");});
```

Alguém poderia me dar uma força?

Comment: Ao invés de usar `$("#lista").html($html);`, use o método "append", ficando assim `$("#lista").append($html);`, pois da forma que está fazendo, toda vez ele está substituindo o último _html_ adicionado.

Comment: Vlw.
Vou fazer a alteração.

Comment: Se der certo, me avise para marcar como resposta. Veja mais informações aqui, caso precise: [W3Schools - jQuery DOM Add](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_add.asp).

Comment: Seu código funciona: https://jsfiddle.net/6osc71sv/ Qual exatamente o problema que está tendo?

Comment: Não consigo criar um id para o botão que gera com cada resultado.
Diferencio o id do botão, id="btn_orc'+orc.numero+'", mas não consigo usa-lo.

Comment: Ele está gerando corretamente, pode editar sua questão colocando o trecho de código que está tentando usá-lo?

Comment: coloquei la ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar um seletor que deteta todos os IDs que começam por uma dada string assim:

```
$('[id^="btn_orc"]').on('click', function() {
   alert("clicou");
});
```

Ou então podes delegar o evento assim:

```
$('#lista').on('click', 'button', function() {
   alert("clicou");
});
```

Ambos fazem o que queres e o `this` dentro da callback é o botão clicado. A primeira solução funciona se os elementos já estiverem na página, o que fazes na linha anterior com `$('#lista').html($html);`, a segunda solução funciona desde que `#lista` exista.

Comment: Deu certo aqui, Sergio.
Muito obrigado.

Comment: O segundo argumento da segunda solução delega o evento click em botões dentro de `#lista` @Sergio? Seria equivalente à `$('#lista > button')`? Ou tem uma finalidade diferente caso o dom tenha sido manipulado via código..

Comment: @LucasCosta sim e não, nesse segundo caso ele permite cliques em botões que sejam adicionados depois desse código ter corrido. Sendo que `$('#lista > button')` é só para elementos `button` descendentes diretos de `#lista` que existam na página quando esse código corre.

Comment: @Sergio te devo uma cerveja, cara.

Vlw mesmo ^^

Comment: @MarcelP aha, eu não bebo cerveja :) mas fico contente por ter ajudado!